# Starting an ExpressJS app using my favourite tools

Tags: express, npm, gulp, zurb-foundation-6

I'm a front end dev who wants make a blog/portfolio site using express js.

I've used codekit in the past to compile,minify & autoprefix my JADE/SASS files,  and to minify my JS files, but I have no idea where to start when going full stack. I've been reading up on gulp (as I assume this will do all the things that codekit does) but I don't understand fully what I need.

Do I need bower aswell? Do I control all the gulp plugins using NPM?

How do I get all this to work with Zurb Foundation 6?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use Express, then Gulp is a good choice. Like you said, gulp can automatically do all the stuff you need; also is very customizable. You don't need Bower to use it, personally I don't use Bower but I use Gulp. All the packages are managed by Node Package Manager (npm). Finally I don't know about support of Zurb Foundation 6. By a quick research I see there is a npm plugin for version 5, but I think there's not one for version 6.

Here's a link with all npm packages and a guide to begin using Gulp:

- https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/
- https://www.npmjs.com/

I hope my answer help you.